# xor matrix multiplication for AES mix column stage

Tags: python, numpy, encryption, matrix, aes

Hi I'm writing program for AES mix column stage. Here I have to multiply two matrices of `(4,4)` shape. The only difference is that while multiplying two matrices I have to take 'xor' instead of where I have to add. e.g

```
a = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
b = np.array([[5,6],[7,8]])
np.dot(a,b) # this gives [[(1*5+2*7),(1*6+2*8)][(3*5+4*7),(3*6+4*8)]]
            # but I want [[((1*5)^(2*7)),((1*6)^(2*8))][((3*5)^(4*7)),((3*6)^(4*8))]]
```

Here's the solution with loops

```
result = [[0,0,0,0],
          [0,0,0,0],
          [0,0,0,0],
          [0,0,0,0]]

# iterate through rows of X
for i in range(len(X)):
   # iterate through columns of Y
   for j in range(len(Y[0])):
      # iterate through rows of Y
      for k in range(len(Y)):
         result[i][j] = result[i][j] ^ (X[i][k] * Y[k][j])
```

How to achieve that without using loops?

Comment: To start off, write a loopy solution for us?

Comment: @Divakar Here you go

Comment: Have a look at how the matrix for mix columns is defined. You either multiply an element of the input vector by 1, 2 or 3, this makes things easier. Also, you don't multiply two matrices, but a matrix and a vector.
And very important: you don't just change the '+' to XOR. You are working in GF(2^8), so you also have to do a special multiplication. Have a look at https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rijndael_MixColumns, for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
xor_ab=np.bitwise_xor.reduce(a[...,None]*b,axis=1)
```

For explanation, consider a rectangular problem for  easier identification:

```
a=np.arange(12).reshape(4,3).astype(object)
b=np.arange(12).reshape(3,4).astype(object)
```

object is to provide the python int arbitrary precision for AES.

products are obtained by broadcasting,

```
c=a[...,None]*b   # dims :  (4,3,1) * ((1),3,4) -> (4,3,4)  , c_ijk =a_ij*b_jk
```

The dot product it then obtained by :

```
dot_ab=c.sum(axis=1)  #  ->(4,4)
In [734]: (dot_ab==a.dot(b)).all()
Out[734]: True
```

Then change to the equivalent xor function :

```
xor_ab=np.bitwise_xor.reduce(a[...,None]*b,axis=1)
```

As an alternative, you can interpret your loops with numba (0.23):

```
from numba import jit
@jit(nopython=True)
def xor(X,Y):
    result=np.zeros((4,4),np.uint64)
    for i in range(len(X)):
    # iterate through columns of Y
      for j in range(Y.shape[1]):
        # iterate through rows of Y
        for k in range(len(Y)):
            result[i,j] = result[i,j] ^ (X[i,k] * Y[k,j])
    return result
```

for a impressive efficiency gain,due to  optimal memory usage.
But you are limited to 32 bits for a and b:

```
In [790]: %timeit xor(a,b)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 580 ns per loop

In [791]: %timeit xor_ab=np.bitwise_xor.reduce(a[...,None]*b,axis=1)
100000 loops, best of 3: 13.2 µs per loop

In [792] (xor(a,b)==np.bitwise_xor.reduce(a[...,None]*b,axis=1)).all()
Out[792]: True
```